# Distance formula correction

Tags: java

I'm practicing for a test I have soon and I know a major portion of it will be using the distance formula. My code runs but I cant help but feel like I'm getting the wrong output.

```
import java.lang.*;
public class Distance
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double x1=4;
      double x2=6;
      double y1=4;
      double y2=10;
      double distance =Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y2,-y1) + Math.pow(x2,-x1));
      System.out.println(distance);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yep it's wrong, see https://brilliant.org/wiki/distance-formula/#distance-between-two-points

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math

Comment: You don't need to import `java.lang`.

Comment: @RC Why shouldn't mathematics be related to programming. He tries to compute it with a program, that' s fine in my opinion. But yeah, the question has other flaws.

Comment: take a look in the Math.pow method description to realize how to fix your code: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double,%20double)

Comment: @Zabuza then don't vote for the question to be closed. There's https://math.stackexchange.com for maths

Comment: @RC Well I wanted to leave it here as discussion for other readers that need to decide whether they vote or not. The thing with [math.se] is that it is only for math, not for programming mathematical stuff. So it would be appropriate for correcting the formula but not for how to implement it with code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in the equation it should be :

```
import java.lang.*;
public class Distance
{
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x1 = 4;
        double x2 = 6;
        double y1 = 4;
        double y2 = 10;
        double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2) + Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2));
        System.out.println(distance);
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Math.pow` takes 2 arguments - the base and the exponent. In the formula you have to square the differences, so it should look like this:

```
double distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2) + Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2));
//                                   ^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^
```